# How to convert a general ellipse from polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, parametric

I have the following equation:

$$a(\alpha)\mathrm{sin}^2(\alpha)-b(\alpha)\mathrm{sin}(\alpha)\mathrm{cos}(\alpha)+c(\alpha)\mathrm{sin}^2(\alpha)=1$$

The authors state that this is the equation of an ellipse as $\alpha$ varies from 0 to 2$\pi$.

I want to plot this ellipse in Cartesian (x,y) coordinates, but I am not sure where to even begin and the authors of the paper do not elaborate. Note that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are known functions.

I've found some answers that talk about converting from polar to Cartesian form (e.g. [here](https://ellipsesconicsections.weebly.com/ellipses-in-polar-form.html) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-equation-x-2-xy+y-2-1-represent-an-ellipse-1) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)), but they generally involve simple cases which are either already in Cartesian coordinates, or do not have coefficients which are also a function of $\alpha$. I feel that one of my primary confusions is how $\alpha$ relates to the parametric form (if at all).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid your equation is incomprehensible to me. What is $\alpha$? And what are the coordinates? Your equation looks like it depends on a single variable: as such, it can only have a discrete set of solutions $\alpha_n$, how could these represent an ellipse?

Comment: Unless there're further contexts, we only have $$\alpha=\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$$ $$\sin \alpha=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ $$\cos \alpha=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$